# How to prevent adding dropdown menu in javafx tabpane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

By default dropdown menu appears even when there is some free space (~20px) and all tabs fit the pane.

[image]

Is it possible to hide or prevent adding dropdown menu in tab pane?

Comment: I have this same issue when all the tabs "fit" however if there is 1 tab less than the full width if it makes sense I find it does not appear...so previously, though not a good solution you can either A. Add more room or B. remove a tab, keep it stored in a list and then re-add/remove as needed....but it seems like there should be a much neater solution...though the api shows no disable function on the dropdown menu of the tabpane.....so...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This way to remove the padding in down button. I hope below CSS help you.

```
.tab-down-button {
-fx-padding: 0;
}

.tab-down-button .arrow {
-fx-padding: 0;
}
```